# What would be my condition if the users membership date is already passed or expired? and I have these kind of code:

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php    
    //These came from my database    
    $_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds'] = $row['dateOfMembershipEnds'];    
  
    if(empty($email)){    
      echo '<script>alert("Email is required!")</script>';    
    }else if(empty($password)){    
      echo '<script>alert("Password is required!")</script>';    
    }else if(strtotime($_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds']) >= date("Y-m-d")){    
      echo '<script>alert("Your Subscription Mr/Ms: '.$_SESSION['username'].' is already expired")        </script>';    
   ?>
```

I am expecting in my code that if the membership date is already expired the statement in my else if   statement should be run.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow chemuel! isn't `strtotime` converts a date into unix timestamp? anyway, you can get current date in php using `date("Y-m-d", time());`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it dateformat like this before compare

```
else if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds'])) >= date("Y-m-d"))
```

The code will look like this

```
    <?php    
//These came from my database    
$_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds'] = $row['dateOfMembershipEnds'];    

if(empty($email)){    
  echo '<script>alert("Email is required!")</script>';    
}else if(empty($password)){    
  echo '<script>alert("Password is required!")</script>';    
}else if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds'])) >= date("Y-m-d")){    
  echo '<script>alert("Your Subscription Mr/Ms: '.$_SESSION['username'].' is already expired")        </script>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are comparing e.g. `'2022-11-11' >= '2022-10-10'`. While this will work, it is a _string comparison_, and it only works because of the time format. If you compared e.g. `'11-11-2022' >= '12-10-2022'` (or `d-m-Y`), it would fail. Better to compare unambiguous timestamps or DateTime::diff for example.

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing `strtotime` with `date()` which will not give you results.  Try this code and see if it works:

```
<?php    
    //These came from my database    
    $_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds'] = $row['dateOfMembershipEnds'];    
  
    if(empty($email)){    
      echo '<script>alert("Email is required!")</script>';    
    }else if(empty($password)){    
      echo '<script>alert("Password is required!")</script>';    
    }else if(strtotime($_SESSION['dateOfMembershipEnds']) <= strtotime("now")){    
      echo '<script>alert("Your Subscription Mr/Ms: '.$_SESSION['username'].' is already expired")        </script>';    
   ?>
```

Also not relevant to your question, It seems like it may be more logical for all of these statements to be just `if` statements and not use `else if`.